# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter

Tags: c#, winforms

**Main form code:**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WFA_KONSPEKT_02
    {
        public partial class ET_Main : Form
        {
          public ET_Main(string permissions) //The program has an authenticator which uses "Permissions"
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                Status.Text = permissions;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Program.cs Code:**

```
Using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WFA_KONSPEKT_02
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            form1 = new ET_Main(); 
            Application.Run(form1);
        }

        private static Form1 form1;

        public static Form1 MainForm
        {
            get { return form1; }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is at " form1 = new ET_Main(); " in program.cs and it says: *"There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'permissions' of 'ET_Main.ET_Main(string)'"*

I've gone through all of the formal "no argument given"-post's to no luck, I just can't seem to find any fix.

Comment: public ET_Main(string permissions="") //The program has an authenticator which uses "Permissions"
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                Status.Text = permissions;

            }

Comment: change the main with the above line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `public ET_Main(string permissions)` constructor requires a parameter called `permissions`, that is a `string`. That's why you can't call it without the parameter `form1 = new ET_Main();`.
You either have to create another constructor that doesn't require the parameter, give it a default value like Joji did in the other answer, or pass the string when calling the method.

```
form1 = new ET_Main("some permissions");
```

Answer (score 1):

replace the code with below one

```
 public ET_Main(string permissions="") //The program has an authenticator which uses "Permissions"
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                Status.Text = permissions;
            }
```

Comment: This assumes the parameter should in fact be optional and does not explain what the problem is.